# Why the reported Influence by appliying the Leave-One-Out method is changing depending on the order of the data?

Tags: loops, tensorflow, logistic-regression

I am trying to calculate the influence using the Leave-One-Out method of each point in a synthetic dataset composed of two clusters with different mean and equal covariance matrices, which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDE4r.png).

And it is generated as follows:

```py
random.seed(2349324)
np.random.seed(2349324)
tf.random.set_seed(2349324)

n = 500
mean = [0,0]
covmat = [[2, 0], [0, 2]]
cov  = covmat   
x1_1, x2_1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, int(n/2)).T
 
mean = [4,4]
cov  = covmat   
x1_2, x2_2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, int(n/2)).T


plt.plot(x1_1, x2_1, 'x')
plt.plot(x1_2, x2_2, 'x')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()

pts1 = list(zip(x1_1, x2_1,itertools.repeat(1)))
pts2 = list(zip(x1_2, x2_2,itertools.repeat(0)))



first_second = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((pts1,pts2),axis=0), columns = ["X1", "X2", "Label"])
second_first = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((pts2,pts1),axis=0), columns = ["X1", "X2", "Label"])
interleaved  = pd.DataFrame([x for t in zip(pts1, pts2) for x in t], columns = ["X1", "X2", "Label"])
```

For each point I am retraining the model, removing said point from the dataset and reporting the influence as:

Influence(z) = Loss(train removing z) - Loss (whole train data)

For each point in the dataset I generate a new dataframe and all these are stored in a list, which corresponds to the output of the `leave_one_out()` method

And for each of these new dataframes, I split them between train and test, and train a new TensorFlow model.

```py
def build_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(2,),kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros)
    ])
    return model


def split(df):
    X = df[["X1","X2"]]
    y = df[["Label"]]
    num_features = 2

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
    x_train, x_test = np.array(x_train, np.float32), np.array(x_test, np.float32)
    x_train, x_test = x_train.reshape([-1, num_features]), x_test.reshape([-1, num_features])
    return(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)



def train_model(builded_model, split_tuple):
    builded_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    builded_model.fit(split_tuple[0], split_tuple[2], epochs=100, batch_size=32,verbose=0)

    loss, accuracy = builded_model.evaluate(split_tuple[1], split_tuple[3])
    return loss





def leave_one_out(df, group_size=1,criteria='single', group_num=4): #Samping could be 'random_inc', 'permutation', 'cascade', 'single' or 'random_exc'
    
    optimal_loss = train_model(build_model(), split(df))
    
    dfs = []
    loss_list = []
    
    if criteria == 'single':
        for i in range(len(df)):
            dfs.append(df.drop(i))
        datasets = list(zip(range(len(df)),dfs))
  
    for dataset in tqdm(datasets):
        loss = train_model(build_model(), split(dataset[1]))
        loss_list.append(loss-optimal_loss)
        
    return pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list(map(itemgetter(0), datasets)),loss_list)),columns=['Index', 'Influence']).set_index('Index')
```

My problem comes from the fact that, depending on the order of the data present in the dataframe with which I work, the influence of the points can change drastically:

```py
first_second = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((pts1,pts2),axis=0), columns = ["X1", "X2", "Label"])
second_first = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((pts2,pts1),axis=0), columns = ["X1", "X2", "Label"])
interleaved  = pd.DataFrame([x for t in zip(pts1, pts2) for x in t], columns = ["X1", "X2", "Label"])
```

[first_second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO9x0.png)

[second_first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWWtO.png)

[interleaved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO6vF.png)

I don't know if the problem originates when retraining a TensorFlow model inside a loop, or if it is related to the way I calculate the Influence.

Could someone explain why this is happening? Is there a way to ensure consistent results regardless of the order in which the data is presented to the model? Are there any best practices or techniques to address this issue?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!